# Powerbar decrease script, pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, game-loop

I'm trying to create a "powerbar." 
In the following code I can press left & right key to increase the bar, and the prg terminates when the bar_start_width > 400 px.
I would like the "powerbar" to decrease while bar_start_width > 0. So, if you stop to press the buttons, the bar will slowly decrease until bar_start_width > 0.
With my code it is slowly decreasing bar_start_width, but not updating the display. The while loop also continues running.

Here is full code:
import time
import random
import pygame

```
import time
import pygame
pygame.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def powerbar(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def game_quit():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_loop():

    decrease_speed = -1
    bar_start_width = 0
    bar_x = 100
    bar_y = 100
    bar_height = 50
    bar_color = black
    x_change = 0

    while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)  # the background color before img

        # Should change so you can ONLY press right after left (or opposite)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

        bar_start_width += x_change

        # Draw powerbar
        powerbar(bar_x, bar_y, bar_start_width, bar_height, bar_color)

        if bar_start_width > 10:
            while True:
                bar_start_width += decrease_speed
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(bar_start_width) #See output in terminal
                if bar_start_width == 0:
                    break


        if bar_start_width > 400:
            game_quit()


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I have tried also to think in terms of a for loop to solve my problems but after long time of trying out different things this is the best I can come up with. 
Can anyone help, or link me to a similar discussion?
Thanks!

Comment: You only need to insert the correct code below `if bar_start_width > 0:`  - what hinders you to do so? This smells like homework

Comment: Please post a [minimal, **complete** and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run and test.

Comment: @PatrickArtner what hinders me to do so is probably my lack of knowledge. That's why I'm posting. If it was homework and I had a tutor why would I even bother asking you guys?

Comment: @skrx the complete code is now uploaded. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have a nested while loop in the main while loop. If I understand you correctly, you want to decrease the width every frame *if* (not *while*) the width is greater than 0. Just remove the while loop and the `time.sleep` call and decrease the width `if bar_start_width > 0:`.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def game_loop():
    decrease_speed = -1
    bar_start_width = 0
    bar_x = 100
    bar_y = 100
    bar_height = 50
    x_change = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        bar_start_width += x_change

        if bar_start_width > 0:
            bar_start_width += decrease_speed
        if bar_start_width <= 0:  # Set it to the minimum width of 1.
            bar_start_width = 1

        if bar_start_width > 400:
            print('> 400')

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        # Draw powerbar
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (bar_x, bar_y, bar_start_width, bar_height))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
```

I've rearranged a few things, because the game logic and the event loop were mixed. You should generally try to separate the event handling, game logic and the rendering.